# How to get result from one table non-matching records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

I have 2 columns in 1 table and both columns have almost the same record (old and new). I am looking for records in a new column which is record isn't in the old column.

Can anyone can help me with that?

Thank you

Comment: See [Why should I register my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/194636) and [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide what you want to retrieve, there are different answers in your questions so far.

to see how many are not matched, do:

```
select SUM(
case when newcol <> oldcol then 1 else 0 end) unmatched
from tablename
```

to see the rows that are not matching, use my first answer and filter by:

```
select 
    oldcol, 
    newcol, 
    case when newcol = oldcol then 'Match' else 'NoMatch' end as MatchTest
from tableName
where oldcol <> newcol
```

If the record in the new column EXISTS in the old column, or simply that row individually? If you're only testing each row individually, try:

```
select 
    oldcol, 
    newcol, 
    case when newcol = oldcol then 'Match' else 'NoMatch' end as MatchTest
from tableName
```